# How to update the reflection texture of an object in a skybox when the center point of the camera changes?

Tags: opengl, camera, texture-mapping, skybox

I am following [this](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps) tutorial to create a skybox/cubemap with environmental mapping. I am having some troubles with the reflection section. When calculating the reflection, the current position, the normal and the camera/eye position are taken into account as in the following fragment shader in the tutorial:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 Position;
out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 cameraPos;
uniform samplerCube skybox;

void main()
{             
    vec3 I = normalize(Position - cameraPos);
    vec3 R = reflect(I, normalize(Normal));
    color = texture(skybox, R);
}
```

and here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 Position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;
    Position = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0f));
}
```

The problem is, with this, if the camera doesn't move around (so the eye position stays the same), but the center of reference of the camera changes, then the texture on the object does not change. This is undesirable. An example would be when you are standing in front of a mirror and you rotate your head left and right, you would expect to see the reflection in the mirror changes.

How can I achieve this effect (i.e. update the reflection texture of the object when the camera center changes)?

**EDIT**: here is a video that shows my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk5akOYnjdc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: "An example would be when you are standing in front of a mirror and you rotate your head left and right, you would expect to see the reflection in the mirror changes." That's only because you move your _eyes_. If you only look with one eye, and rotate around its optical center, nothing would change.  The light reflected from each point of the mirror's surface to any direction is of course independent of the viewer's position, and the light received from it at any fixed viewling location in space will not vary with the viewer's orientation (with ideal pinhole camera, reality is more complex).

Comment: So what you are saying is, the current behavior is the correct one?

Comment: Yes. With perspective projection, rotating a camera without changing its position results in a new image wich is just trapezodially distorted to the orignal image (and of course seeing parts which were out of view before, and vice versa). This is not a perfect model of reality - we have lenses in our eye, not a pinhole, but it is a very useful approximation which will not introduce any significant errors in this context.

Comment: Wait, when you say "seeing parts which were out of view before", isn't that exactly what my question is about? So rotating a camera without changing its position does indeed change the reflection texture on an object in the scene?

Comment: no, that's not what I meant. If you would see the mirror completely before and after the rotation, the "image" you would see on the mirror would stay the same - you could bake in the reflection to a single texture and draw a textured quad, and the image would be always valid as long as the camera position isn't changed. If you were close to the mirror so that it is not completely in view, by changing your orientation you would just see different parts of the mirror, but the light you see from each point of that surface would still not change - and the texture approach would work as well.

Comment: Here is a video that I take: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk5akOYnjdc&feature=youtu.be . I moved the camera left/right, up/down and also rotate it. Can you take a look to see if it's normal? Particularly, when moving the camera further away and closer to the cube, the texture on the cube stays the same, and so is when the camera rotates.